# PIc16f886 not convert string to int

Tags: microcontroller, pic, microchip, hi-tech-c

i'm trying to read the saved value from eeprom, reading eeprom as a char is easily done after convert the read data into integer is not working
here my code is :

```
char AM[];
int per,vt,vtt;
AM[0]=eeprom_read(ecur[0]);
__delay_ms(50);
AM[1]=eeprom_read(ecur[1]);
__delay_ms(50);
AM[2]=eeprom_read(ecur[2]);
__delay_ms(50);
AM[3]=0;
vcur=atoi(AM);
per=0,vt=0;vtt=0;
per=vcur/100;
vt=vcur+(per*30);
vtt=vcur-(per*30);

LCD_Clear();
LCD_Set_Cursor(1, 1);
LCD_Write_String(vcur);
}

char AM[];
int per,vt,vtt;
AM[0]=eeprom_read(ecur[0]);
__delay_ms(50);
AM[1]=eeprom_read(ecur[1]);
__delay_ms(50);
AM[2]=eeprom_read(ecur[2]);
__delay_ms(50);
AM[3]=0;
vcur=atoi(AM);
//per=AM1;
//vt=AM2;
//vtt=AM3;
//vcur=per*100;
//vcur=vcur+(vt*10);
//vcur=vcur+vtt;
per=0,vt=0;vtt=0;
per=vcur/100;
vt=vcur+(per*30);
vtt=vcur-(per*30);

LCD_Clear();
LCD_Set_Cursor(1, 1);
LCD_Write_String(vcur);
```

ive already tried atoi,xtoi, not working also tried to read the value from eeprom as int not woking

Comment: Well, how do you save the int value into the EEPROM? Where is your `eeprom_write` routine? We need to see it to be able to say something. By the way what compiler do you use, Hi-Tech C or XC8?

Comment: In what way "it does not work"? You must provide much more details. Also, debug it!

Comment: Also, LCD_Write_String() seems to want strings, but you pass it a number? Do you see any compiler warnings or errors?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]". Then come back and [edit] your question, adding a [mre] and explaining how it does not work. What do you expect in detail, and what happens instead? The source as currently presented is incomplete, so we cannot help you.

Comment: my eeprom routine:
````
adisp();
short int fv=0x00;
eeprom_write(ecur[0],fv);
__delay_ms(50);
eeprom_write(ecur[1],fv);
__delay_ms(50);
eeprom_write(ecur[2],fv);
__delay_ms(5000);
adisp();
eeprom_write(ecur[0],am1);
__delay_ms(50);
eeprom_write(ecur[1],am2);
__delay_ms(50);
eeprom_write(ecur[2],am3);
__delay_ms(5000);
adisp();
````
in adisp in read a value from adc and store in am1,am2,am3 integers.

Comment: my atctual problem is atoi is not working

Comment: Please read _all_ of my comment. You are supposed to add new information and clarification to your question by [edit]ing it. Do not post comments. There is a clear sign against doing so: you cannot format code.

Comment: "_is not working_" does not tell us anything. Please be specific with your error description.

Answer (score 0):

The user [Active watersaver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22634739/active-watersaver) seems very new to creating code for an embedded controller as resource limited as the PIC16F866.

Reading the Microchip documentation and analyzing the implementation of the `eeprom_write();` function would likewise be helpful.

What the user does not appear to understand is that the EEPROM in the PIC16F866 will only store data in octets (8-bit chunks). Larger data types like `int` and `long` must be separated into octets, each octet written to several EEPROM addresses. For reading, all the EEPROM addresses of the octets associated with an `int` or `long` must be read from the EEPROM, then reassembled in to the associated data type.